# How to match multiple case classes and extract same (-named) arguments?

Tags: scala, inheritance, pattern-matching, case-class, extractor

Consider the following contrived example of implementing a unary & binary operations on real number expressions.

```
abstract class DoubleE
case class Negate(x: DoubleE) extends DoubleE
case class Reciprocal(x: DoubleE) extends DoubleE
case class Mult(lhs: DoubleE, rhs: DoubleE) extends DoubleE
case class Div(lhs: DoubleE, rhs: DoubleE) extends DoubleE
...
// a lot more binary operations
```

Now, I want to do something like:

```
(e: DoubleE) match {
   case DoubleEUnary(x) => ... // use x ...
   case DoubleEBinary(a, b) => ... // use a and b ...
}
```

and sometimes I would even like to refer to the matched type as well; for example

```
e match {
  case DoubeEBinary(a, b) => DoubleEBinary(b, a)
  ...
}
```

Some of the failed attempts I have tried:

- `abstract case class DoubleEBinary(a: DoubleE, b: DoubleE)` + extend from that, but this is not allowed: Error: *... case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes*
- Hinted by the error above:

  ```
  abstract case class DoubleEBinary(a: DoubleE, b: DoubleE)
      def unapply(binOp: DoubleEBinary) = Some((a, b))
  ```

  which doesn't work either: *Error: not found: value DoubleEBinary*
- Trying to use case aliases

  - `case binOp @ (Mult(a, b) | Div(a, b) | ...) => ...`
  - `case binOp(a, b) @ (Mult(_, _) | Div(_, _) | ...) => ...`
  - `case (binOp @ Mult(a, b)) | (binOp @ Div(a, b)) => ...`

One thing I haven't tried, is overloading with nested functions, which seems like an overkill...

Is there a good way match multiple case classes in scenarios similar to the above?

*Note*: Adding additional methods, classes, traits in the inheritance is fine.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it doesn't solve your problem, but note that the concrete class is necessary because abstract classes cannot be instantiated, if you want to you have to drop the abstract modifier.

Answer (score 2):

The hint in the error message is to do:

```
scala> object Binary { def unapply(e: Mult) = Mult.unapply(e) ; def unapply(e: Div) = Div.unapply(e) }
defined object Binary

scala> Div(null,null) match { case Binary(a,b) => (a,b) }
res3: (DoubleE, DoubleE) = (null,null)
```

Sorry, about to sleep here, that would be better expressed as `unapply(b: Binary)` or as `DoubleE.unapply(d: DoubleE)` which matches on the subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

As of Scala 2.13, probably well beforehand, you can do exactly what you've typed